# How To: Use a Type definition returned from a function?

Tags: .net, reflection, gettype

Please how can I use a Type definition returned from a function?

The function below compiles, but I get: ***BC30002  "Type 'DB.ResolveType' is not defined."*** when i try to use it

```
Public NotInheritable Class DB
    Public Shared Function ResolveType(type As String) As Type
        Select Case type
            Case "Stop-Action-Request" : Return GetType(cheque_action)
            Case "Cheque-Book-Request" : Return GetType(cheque_book_request)
            Case "Confirm-Action-Request" : Return GetType(cheque_action)
            Case "FX-Transfer-Request" : Return GetType(cheque_action)
            Case "Mobile-Banking-Request" : Return GetType(mobile_banking_request)
            Case "SMS-Alerts-Request" : Return GetType(sms_alert_request)
        End Select

        Return Nothing
    End Function
End Class

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Try
            Dim d = Request.Form("payload")

            Dim r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of request)(d)

            ** this line fails: **
            Dim p = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DB.ResolveType(r.req_type))(r.data)

            DB.new_request(r.req_type, r.src, r.data)
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: You cannot use generics like that. If you have a generic method you have to provide a constant defined type which is known at compile-time. In your example you try to provide a type which is dynamically resolved during run-time which is not possible.

Comment: @AlexB. what would be the preferred method of achieving this or similar. I want to dynamically determine which type to jsonDecode. I have strings that i can lookup to determine which decoding (class) to apply.

Comment: Just use an other overload of DeserializeObject, like `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(r.data, DB.ResolveType(r.req_type))`

Comment: @AlexB. ... I had never used the other overloads. Thanks!

Comment: Your welcome. I put all together in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use generics like that.

If you have a generic method you have to provide a constant defined type which is known at compile-time, e.g. `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of String)(data)`

In your example, you try to provide a type which is dynamically resolved during run-time which is not possible.

Just use an other overload of `DeserializeObject` if you want to the object type to be dynamically resolved, e.g.

`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(r.data, DB.ResolveType(r.req_type))`

Answer (score 0):

your return-statements seem to be correct.
but you can not write something like "DeserializeObject(Of DB.ResolveType(r.req_type))(r.data)"

generics operations can have *types* as arguments (example: "  Dim p = MyType.MyFunction(of String)(argument)") but you can not use an *obbject* (of the type "Type" or any other type) instead of the type-argument